# Why is the schema.org JSON-LD representation so small?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

When requesting the schema.org vocabulary in JSON-LD form (which can be accomplished via the following request headers):

```
Accept: application/ld+json, application/json;q=0.9, application/javascript;q=0.5, text/javascript;q=0.5, text/plain;q=0.2, */*;q=0.1
```

The response document (snipped included at the bottom) appears to be very small and incomplete at first blush.  It only lists a few attributes, and does not seem to have any types like those shown in the [full hierarchy](http://schema.org/docs/full.html).  Even looking at a single type, http://schema.org/CreativeWork, there are many attributes that don't appear in the document (ex: [keywords](http://schema.org/keywords)).  Even the attribute [name](http://schema.org/name), which should be a part of every Thing, doesn't appear in the result.

Why are all of the attributes mentioned on schema.org not included in this document?

```js
{
    "@context":    {
        "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
        "acceptsReservations": { "@type": "@id" },
        "additionalType": { "@type": "@id" },
        "applicationCategory": { "@type": "@id" },
        "applicationSubCategory": { "@type": "@id" },
        "arrivalTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "artform": { "@type": "@id" },
        "availabilityEnds": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "availabilityStarts": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "availableFrom": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "availableThrough": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "birthDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "bookingTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "checkinTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "checkoutTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "codeRepository": { "@type": "@id" },
        "commentTime": { "@type": "Date" },
        "contentUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "dateCreated": { "@type": "Date" },
        "dateIssued": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "dateModified": { "@type": "Date" },
        "datePosted": { "@type": "Date" },
        "datePublished": { "@type": "Date" },
        "deathDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "departureTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "discussionUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "dissolutionDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "doorTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "downloadUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "dropoffTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "embedUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "endDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "endTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "expectedArrivalFrom": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "expectedArrivalUntil": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "expires": { "@type": "Date" },
        "featureList": { "@type": "@id" },
        "foundingDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "gameLocation": { "@type": "@id" },
        "gamePlatform": { "@type": "@id" },
        "guidelineDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "hasMap": { "@type": "@id" },
        "image": { "@type": "@id" },
        "installUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "isBasedOnUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "labelDetails": { "@type": "@id" },
        "lastReviewed": { "@type": "Date" },
        "license": { "@type": "@id" },
        "logo": { "@type": "@id" },
        "map": { "@type": "@id" },
        "maps": { "@type": "@id" },
        "material": { "@type": "@id" },
        "memoryRequirements": { "@type": "@id" },
        "menu": { "@type": "@id" },
        "modifiedTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "namedPosition": { "@type": "@id" },
        "orderDate": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "ownedFrom": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "ownedThrough": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "paymentDue": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "paymentUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "pickupTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "prescribingInfo": { "@type": "@id" },
        "previousStartDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "priceValidUntil": { "@type": "Date" },
        "publishingPrinciples": { "@type": "@id" },
        "relatedLink": { "@type": "@id" },
        "releaseDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "releaseNotes": { "@type": "@id" },
        "replyToUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "requirements": { "@type": "@id" },
        "roleName": { "@type": "@id" },
        "sameAs": { "@type": "@id" },
        "scheduledPaymentDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "scheduledTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "screenshot": { "@type": "@id" },
        "serviceUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "significantLink": { "@type": "@id" },
        "significantLinks": { "@type": "@id" },
        "sport": { "@type": "@id" },
        "startDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "startTime": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "storageRequirements": { "@type": "@id" },
        "surface": { "@type": "@id" },
        "targetUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "temporal": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "thumbnailUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "ticketToken": { "@type": "@id" },
        "trackingUrl": { "@type": "@id" },
        "uploadDate": { "@type": "Date" },
        "url": { "@type": "@id" },
        "validFrom": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "validThrough": { "@type": "DateTime" },
        "validUntil": { "@type": "Date" },
        "warning": { "@type": "@id" },
        "webCheckinTime": { "@type": "DateTime" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this isn't the definition of the vocabulary but just Schema.org's JSON-LD context i.e., a mapping from nice, short JSON terms to full URLs. See http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#the-context for details.

The reason why it doesn't map each property and class one by one is that it uses the `@vocab` shortcut which is also described in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#default-vocabulary